# Is there an equivalent to ⌘ + D in the new save dialogs?

Tags: applications, keyboard

In Snow Leopard and prior, when clsoing a window with unsaved changes, the system would suggest to either save, cancel or discard the changes from keyboard shortcuts. You could:

- save <kbd>return</kbd>
- cancel <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>
- discard the changes <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

The Lion save dialog that gets summoned instead of the "Would you like to save?" dialog works differently:

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>return</kbd> still work<sup>1</sup>, but <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> has no effect.

Is there a new keyboard shortcut to discard?

<sub>1. I'm not in front of my Mac right now; *IIRC they work*, but maybe I'm wrong.</sub>

Comment: ⌘D actually DOES have an effect; it sets the save destination to the Desktop, as it always has in open/save file dialogs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌫</kbd>

Pressing Command-Delete (or perhaps more commonly known as backspace) also does the same trick.

That's all there is to it!

Answer (score 9):

In Terminal.app, you can change this back to the old behaviour using

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSSavePanelStandardDesktopShortcutOnly -bool YES
```

To revert to the default behaviour, set

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSSavePanelStandardDesktopShortcutOnly -bool NO
```

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature!

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm not quite used to the new way. When doing this, does Cmd-Delete do anything?

Comment: cmd-delete also works when this is in place. best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the application. For example, in Powerpoint 2011 ⌘D still works, ⌘⌫ does nothing in the dialog.

I guess it's personal preference, I like to use Space (or Tab until Don't Save is in focus, Space) for this action.